# How to apply number delimiting to a whole Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, locale

I've tried to play with the **config/locales/en.yml** file, changing number, format, separator, delimiter values. 
But as Ive understood, this config file only sets preference for **number_with_delimiter** helper function. It would be too hard and stupid to add this helper to every place where the numbers are being used. My question is: How to apply a certain delimiter to maybe a class (Integer, Float) or generally speaking, to all the numbers are being used in application? ex. 1000000 -> 1 000 000 (1,000,000)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by editing **helper** in which the method **format_object** was rendering the values of an object depending on its type. I've wrapped Fixnum(Integer) case into **number_with_delimiter**

Answer (score 0):

How many places with number in your templates you will be have? I don't think it can be problem, you only have to add this function in presentation layer, or you can use regex to add function call